# Please help me with this diode identification - i can't find company name and datasheet

Tags: diodes, high-voltage

[image]

I have a problem with this part, can't find the datasheet and company name. The logo is very characteristic and I put it in the left corner. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What kind of equipment did you find this in? What country was it made in?

Comment: It seems to be like a Sescosem part, the former Thomson company well before it became ST.

Comment: Seems to be 500V, 20A, and reverse polarity. There was Thomson/Sescosem parts marked 21R2, 26R2 etc, manufactured about 1975. https://www.web-bcs.com/diode/dc/20/26R2.html

Comment: Super info! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be like a Sescosem part, the former Thomson company well before it became ST. Look at the TO3 transistor below, logo is very close:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it looks the same, thank you!

Comment: I was still wearing short pans when Sescosem was still alive! And who remembers Plessey semis and SGS-Ates : )

Comment: @Verbal Kint Huh, Plessey are modern - they used silicon. I can remember (and used) Mullard and Newmarket germanium devices.